# Search for strings with apostrophes in SAS PROC SQL

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Is there a way to avoid the warning for the following code? I'm not so much interested in a system option to turn off warnings, rather, I am curious as to whether or not there is a better way to write this query.

```
data quotey; 
input string $9.;
cards;
shouldn't
wouldn't
couldn't
dont
won't
;
run;
proc print ; run;

ods html close; ods html ;


title 'Hmmm...';
proc sql ; 
select * from quotey 
where string like "%dn't%"
;quit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different ways to handle this, but the simplest is to use `contains` instead of `like`.  Of course that wouldn't work in *all* cases, but it would in yours.

```
proc sql ; 
select * from quotey 
where string contains "dn't"
;
quit;
```

There are a lot of messy ways to handle it otherwise.  The simplest is to use single quotes (to prevent macro resolution), but then you need to double your single quote/apostrophe.

```
proc sql ; 
select * from quotey 
where string like '%dn''t%'
;
quit;
```

You could also use `%nrstr` in a few ways (it prevents characters from being used to resolve a macro).  Here's one.

```
proc sql ; 
select * from quotey 
where string like "%nrstr(%%)dn't%nrstr(%%)"
;quit;
```

Here you have to double the `%` character (As it's used as an 'escape' sort of).

Comment: May I know why doubling the single quote?

Comment: That's how you escape a quote mark in a string quoted with the same quote mark type in SAS.

Answer (score 1):

Also try to use regular expression:

```
title 'Hmmm...';
proc sql ; 
select * from quotey 
where prxmatch("/dn't/",string)>1;
;quit;
```

Comment: Why `>1' ?  Shouldn't it be `>=1`?